# Why onchange function is not calling for DropDownList using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to call on change function for DropDownList when it change. This drop down is created dynamically,

Here is my code:

```js
$('.chequeTable .selected .tbDDLReqNo').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  alert('yessss');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="chequeTable">
  <tr class="selected">
    <td class="tdReqNo">
      <select class="tbDDLReqNo">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1111">1111</option>
        <option value="2222">2222</option>
        <option value="3333">3333</option>
        <option value="4444">4444</option>
        <option value="5555">5555</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `.on('change', ':checkbox'` is a delegate where `change` means event and `:checkbox` means selector. So if you have a checkbox inside the dropdown, changing its value might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `on` method is the `selector`. So, you have to use in the following way :

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

```js
$('.chequeTable').on('change','.tbDDLReqNo', function () {
    alert('yessss');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="chequeTable">
    <tr class="selected">
        <td class="tdReqNo">
            <select class="tbDDLReqNo">
                 <option></option>
                 <option value="1111">1111</option>
                 <option value="2222">2222</option>
                 <option value="3333">3333</option>
                 <option value="4444">4444</option>
                 <option value="5555">5555</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Alexandry-lonutMihai yes, your answer is correct. But can you tell me why you used `document` there?

Comment: @mohamedfaiz This might help: http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Comment: `On` method triggers `bubbling`. That said, events occur all the way up to the `body` and the `document` or another element you want. In this example I used `document` but you can also use `body` or `.chequeTable` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the dropdown list change event using the class name `.tbDDLReqNo` as the selector. There is no `checkbox` so there is nothing to `check`.

```js
$('.tbDDLReqNo').on('change', function () {
    alert('yessss');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="chequeTable">
    <tr class="selected">
        <td class="tdReqNo">
            <select class="tbDDLReqNo">
                 <option></option>
                 <option value="1111">1111</option>
                 <option value="2222">2222</option>
                 <option value="3333">3333</option>
                 <option value="4444">4444</option>
                 <option value="5555">5555</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Jquery Selector like that also :**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.tbDDLReqNo').on('change', function () {
    alert('The value has been changed! , and you have been '+$(this).val()+ ' selected.');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="chequeTable">
    <tr class="selected">
        <td class="tdReqNo">
            <select class="tbDDLReqNo">
                 <option></option>
                 <option value="First">First</option>
                 <option value="Second">Second</option>
                 <option value="Third">Third</option>            
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: including your code inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.